# Error global variables Sudoku

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, global-variables

I have a program Sudoku recursive, is working well, but I would like to add a counter to solutions, I have tried numerous changes to the code that could do this, but it didn't work, finally tried a solution using global variables as would implement in C as a last resort, and also did not work, but I don't know if I used this variable correctly, the code in python I returned the following error:

```
File "~/CCR/UserFiles/Marcilio/Sudoku/sudoku.py", line 176, in Sudoku
    contador += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'contador'
```

Follow the code, with the global variable, or if there is another way to resolve and can suggest me thank you:

```
contador = 0

def Sudoku(Mat, lin, col):   
    lin, col = ProcuraCasas(Mat)    
    if lin == -1 and col == -1:
        if TestaMatrizPreenchida(Mat):
            contador += 1
            ImprimaMatriz(Mat)
            print("\t")
        else: print("Preenchimento incorreto")    
    else:
        for candidato in range (1, 10):
            if VerificaCandidato (Mat, lin, col, candidato) is True:
                Mat[lin][col] = candidato     
                Sudoku(Mat, lin, col)           
        Mat[lin][col] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the variable as global inside of the function:

```
contador = 0

def Sudoku(Mat, lin, col):
    global contador
```